# Retrieving Scoped Relationships from A Model

Tags: php, yii

Deals scope:

```
public function scopes()
{
    return array(
        'published'=>array(
            'condition'=>'offer_end >= "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . '"',
        )
    );
}
```

Controller Code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 't.slug=:slug';
$criteria->params = array(':slug'=>$_GET['slug']);


Category::model()->with('deals:published')->findAll($criteria);
```

In the above code, I am trying to retrieve associated `deals` related to a `category`. They (deals) should also need to be using a scope, `published`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, using 'with' doesn't work if you also send in a criteria object. If you instead specify the with as part of your criteria object, it should fix your problem. All your scopes look good